# UX - how and where to place the save button on large forms

Tags: jquery, forms, save, user-experience

I have a page which uses jQuery tabs down the left hand side.

There are about 8 tabs, within each tab are forms which holds approx 10-20 items on each form within each tab.

How and what is the best way to show the 'SAVE' button or some identification that the items on the form on each of the tabs are being saved?

The save button would need to save ALL fields on all of the tabs, but not sure best way to present this on screen, for best user experience.

Comment: i agree with @Nick; if there are validation errors on hidden tabs, it would be tedious for the user to go back to each tab to correct errors. I would recommend a wizard-style form; allow the user to save the data entered on each 'tab' before moving on to the next one.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single tab with many items you may want to put a save button on the top and bottom.

Additionally, I think it's a bad idea to have any of these save buttons save multiple tabs. 
If I make changes in 4 different tabs and then click save on the 5th tab and there is validation errors you're going to run into a nickel and dime situation - The user is going to have to click through all of the tabs to find them.

A better approach is to have each tab contain its own form, which you can you conveniently display validation messages for that one tab.

Think about this from a users perspective, wouldn't you hate making a bunch of changes only to be presented by half a dozen error messages, and then have to click through each tab to fix them?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Nick. Rather than a series of tabs with a single save button, it might be a better idea to use a wizard style layout without validation at each step. Each step has a back and next button, and validation happens each time you hit next for that step alone. The last step has a Save button rather than a next button. Also, between the back and next buttons you have a progress bar that displays where the user is in the process.

I've built UIs like this and I've found they work very well for a lot of use cases.